# Problem about martingale, bounded stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times, filtrations

Let $F_n$, $n\geq0$, be a filtration, and let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of r.v.'s such that $X_n\in F_n$ and $E\lvert X_n \rvert < \infty$. Show that if $EX_T = EX_0$ for all bounded stopping times T, $X_n$ is a martingale.

This is my problem. Actually, I can show that If T is bounded stopping time then $EX_T =EX_0$. But, this isn't problem.

How can I solve above problem? or any hints please.

Comment: It follows from the martingale stopping theorem.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I think the martingale stopping theorem gives the other direction, i.e. that if $(X_n)$ is a martingale then $\mathbb{E}[X_T] = \mathbb{E}[X_0]$ for all bounded stopping times $T$.

Comment: @user6247850, it depends on which version we are speaking about: there are versions of this theorem with this direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definition of a martingale, we want to show that $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal F_s] = X_s$ for all $s < t$, which is equivalent to showing that for all $A \in \mathcal F_s$ we have $\mathbb{E}[X_t 1_A] = \mathbb{E}[X_s 1_A]$.  We define a stopping time $\tau := t 1_A + s 1_{A^c}$ (check this is a stopping time!), and from the hypotheses we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_s] = \mathbb{E}[X_0] &= \mathbb{E}[X_\tau] = \mathbb{E}[X_t 1_A + X_s 1_{A^c}]
\end{align*}

so $\mathbb{E}[X_s 1_A] = \mathbb{E}[X_t 1_A]$.  We conclude $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal F_s] = X_s$ and therefore $(X_n)$ is a martingale since we already had that it was adapted and integrable.

Comment: Thanks. I understand perfectly. Your answer is awsome. But, Why $EX_s = EX_0$??  @user6247850

Comment: @someeed It's because the constant $s$ is also a bounded stopping time